# Implementing parallel exceptions to get trees of errors?

Tags: c#, java, c++, error-handling

Consider the following code:

```
// this method should add numbers, the requirements are:
// x >= 3 and y <= 5
int add(int x, int y)
{
  if(x < 3) throw new ...;
  if(y > 5) throw new ...;
}
```

It's absolutely traditional approach, but in case you pass invalid values for both x and y, you'll only get an exception for x. Why x and not y? Just because you first check x and only then y. Why? That's basically the main question.

In the code above, there's absolutely no sense in checking x before y or y before x. Just because the idea of execution flow in a single thread, some statements are executed before others.

I'm thinking about implementing a mechanism for working with *parallel exceptions*. The idea is, if there are 2 statements that can be executed simultaneously (execution order doesn't matter) and both of them throw exceptions, I'd like to be able to handle *all* these exception. The pseudo-code is like following:

```
// this method should add numbers, the requirements are:
// x >= 3 and y <= 5
int add(int x, int y)
{
  parallel
  {
    if(x < 3) throw new ...;
    if(y > 5) throw new ...;
  } // point A

  return x + y;
}
```

Somewhere at point A the cumulative exception is thrown. Have you ever seen this approach before, or may be even implemented something of that kind? The main goal here is that if you have a complicated operation, that uses a number of another operation, and the "topmost" operation fails for some reason, you're able to get full diagnostics for what was wrong: not a single error (or a number of nested errors), but a *tree* of errors.

The questions are:

1. What do you think?
2. Have you seen it before?
3. Have you tried implementing something similar?

Comment: I think it would be a lot of work for little benefit.

Comment: I am trying to see how one would catch potential parallel exceptions in a meaningful way.  Why not just make a better exception object to throw that can contain multiple error indicators?

Comment: This is a total duplicate- you already posted this question once.

Comment: @DeadMG: I know. I've delete the old one and re-posted with more clear definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to enforce a set of business rules.

One approach is to create a collection of broken rules and add specific broken rules (e.g. input too short, input must be alphanumeric) as separate elements of that collection, then throw a `BrokenRulesException` that includes the collection of broken rules as a parameter.

That allows the caller to fully understand what's wrong with the input without changing any language semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx)?

Comment: I didn't know AggregateException is available in .NET 4.  That's a good find.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with:

```
    int add(int x, int y)
    {
      if(x < 3 || y > 5) 
       throw new Error("Incorrect Parameter, x must be >= 3 and y must be <= 5");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would be extraordinarily difficult without implementing something called a `continuation` -- the ability to return the current state of a function for delayed execution.

Basically, the problem is that instead of an exception (or, rather, a thrown... thing as you do not always have to throw an Exception object in all languages) being a message that `a point which cannot be handled` has been reached, it would have to return both that and the ability to force continuation past that point anyway. (Thus, you would need `continuations`)

Additionally, at least on the lower level, this would force the language to always throw an object in those cases. Throwing an int, on the other hand, is occasionally useful.

All of that said, there is nothing stopping you from, say, implementing a macro which works similar to how you've described.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this method should add numbers, the requirements are:
// x >= 3 and y <= 5
int add(int x, int y)
{
  if(x < 3 && y > 5) throw new ...;
  if(x < 3) throw new ...;
  if(y > 5) throw new ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't this be fairly easily done, without the need for AggregateExceptions or similar:

```
string ErrorMessage="";
if(x<3) ErrorMessage += "x must be >=3\n";
if(y>5) ErrorMessage += "y must be <=5\n";
if(ErrorMessage!="") throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
```

if a string is too simple, it's easy to do something similar with a more complex object type.

Comment: The goal was not just too build a kind of heavily detailed error message, but to build an interpretable description of "bad context". Good point though ;-)